# VS Code File Explorer Does Not Move Up File Tree (Windows)

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10

The file explorer in my VS Code is stuck on a repo that is three steps down the file tree from the C drive (Flatiron_Work); it will not allow me to access anything further up the tree, such as Users or username (mngav)  It is installed correctly in C:\users{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code .  I have tried to open files, folders and workspaces further up the tree but nothing works.  Am I going to need to remove and reinstall?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: @tHeSiD - just added screenshots

Comment: If you have opened VSCode in that folder, it will only list the files/folders within it, it will not look to above folders. If you want, you can use `File -> Close Folder` and re open which ever folder you want again.

Comment: oye, I feel stupid.  Thank you for your help!